# How to output a list in a forargs# wiki template

Tags: templates, wiki

I would like to output a list in my wiki template using `forargs#`

I call my template like this

```
{{MyTemplate|RTLA1=US|RTLA2=FR}}
```

Then inside `MyTemplate` I have

```
{{#forargs:RTLA| key | value |
*{{#var:value}}:
}}
```

Which output something like this:

- US: *FR:

Because it seems the templating engine doesn't generate a new line inside the `forargs#` so it doesn't render the list. I tried with `\n` and even `<br>` but it doesn't work.

If there are some wiki template expert, I could use some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `<nowiki/>`

```
{{#forargs:RTLA| key | value | <nowiki/>
*{{#var:value}}:
}}
```